# Pegar valor em um iframe via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu tenho um código que está em um arquivo externo e preciso carregá-lo via Javascript, porém não sei como fazer isso. Eu já tentei de diversas formas, e pelo visto a melhor seria com um iframe, porém nem isso.
A ideia era usar a função load() do jQuery, mas tem um detalhe: o código está sendo rodado localmente, então isso não funciona devido às permissões HTTP e afins.
Então eu pensei em fazer um iframe assim:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="script1.html"></iframe>
```

Então tentei assim:

```
var text = $("#iframe").val();
```

Não me retornou nada, então fiz umas tags no arquivo e tentei assim:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find("html").html();
```

Mesmo assim, nada. Então tentei dessa forma:

```
var iBody = $("#iframe").contents().find("body");
var myContent = iBody.find("#myContent");
```

O problema é que o Chrome retorna um erro:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Ou seja, será não tem como carregar um arquivo localmente? Eu apenas preciso de um arquivo limpo com os códigos para carregar depois, eu até colocaria diretamente dentro de uma tag dentro da página, mas isso ficaria **muito** sujo, visto que outra pessoa irá mudar o código.
Obs.: Esse código que deve ser carregado a que me refiro é um documento de texto, ou seja, você pode interpretar como quiser, simplesmente, são várias frases, nada de especial quanto a isso.

Comment: Quando dizes "arquivo externo" queres dizer noutro site ou outro arquivo que não aquele onde tens a iFrame (local, no mesmo servidor)?

Comment: Está na mesma pasta do arquivo HTML, e os arquivos não estão sendo rodados em um servidor, é apenas o simples clique duplo no "index.html".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é possivel localmente por causa das proteções que os Browsers têm.

Podes conseguir pôr isso a funcionar se tiveres o ficheiro num servidor e se o servidor em questão aceitar pedidos de outros dominios, senão a regra é a mesma.

Esta regra de segurança é conhecida por [CORS (compartilhamento de recursos cross-origem)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/129), uma recomendação de segurança da W3C que foi adotada pelos Browsers para impedir acesso a dados indevidamente.

Comment: Entendo, então não tem nenhum outro jeito de carregar esse texto externo localmente? E aliás, obrigado pela dica de vir para o site em português, o desconhecia ;)

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida localmente não. De nada!

Answer (score 0):

O Chrome não permite carregar um arquivo do sistema de arquivos usando XmlHttpRequest (Ajax). Eu mesmo já tive esse problema ao testar arquivos HTML com chamadas Ajax.

Cada browser aplica diferentes regras sobre carregamento de arquivos de mesma origem (CORS), quando se trata de arquivos locais (carregados via `file://...`, que é o que ocorre quando você dá um duplo clique no documento HTML na pasta).

Achei algumas recomendações em rodar o Chrome com a flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`, mas não obtive sucesso.

Para resolver este problema, eu criei o meu próprio mini servidor Web que roda em uma pasta específica. Você pode tentar usar o *Node.js* para fazer algo parecido.

Você também pode tentar outro browser que seja menos restritivo.