# Requisição de arquivo .txt via AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estou iniciando nos meus estudos com Javascript com interações com o servidor, e logo de cara não consigo recuperar um arquivo de texto para ser mostrado via um alert do Javascript.
Pelo o que estudei, é preciso que o arquivo esteja em um servidor. Em outras palavras, para fazer uma requisição é preciso ser através de um "http://". A princípio, estou fazendo isso localmente com o Apache. E mesmo assim, não está dando certo.

Segue o código:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
        //alert("Ok");
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
            if( ajax.readyState == 4) { 
                alert(ajax.responseText);
            }                                 
        }
        ajax.open("POST", "http://localhost/ajax/texto.txt");
        ajax.send(null); //Inicia a requisição para o servidor.
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
 <h1 id="button">Teste</h1>
```

O resulto que me aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro que aparece no console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor... Aguardo nortes!
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Política de mesma origem

Existe uma funcionalidade de segurança nos navegadores chamada [**Same-origin policy** (Política de mesma origem)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem) que é responsável por restringir o acesso de recursos disponíveis em servidores diferentes do servidor de onde a página atual veio. Essa política é importante pois previne que um site acesse seus dados pessoais provenientes de outro site.

## Porque essa política é importante?

Imagine que você acessa uma página em um site malicioso. Essa página, sem que você perceba, poderia realizar uma requisição AJAX para outro site (uma rede social, internet banking). Se você estiver logado neste outro site, o site terá acesso completo a toda informação visível nele. Isto seria uma gigante brecha de segurança.

Logo, os navegadores restringem, por padrão, o acesso a qualquer recurso que não seja proveniente da mesma origem que a página tentando acessá-lo.

## Soluções

Seu problema bate nessa restrição: seu arquivo de texto está disponível no domínio `localhost`, enquanto a página tentando acessá-lo está sendo recuperada via sistema de arquivos local (note a URL: `file:///C:/Users/...`). Logo o navegador bloqueia o acesso.

A melhor solução para seu problema é tornar sua página HTML disponível no mesmo servidor do seu arquivo de texto (sua instância do Apache) e acessar a página por lá (algo como `http://localhost/ajax.html`). Isso vai fazer com que o navegador identifique que o recurso está no mesmo domínio da página e permita o acesso.

Em outros casos mais complexos, onde é realmente necessário que páginas acessem recursos em domínios diferentes pode-se configurar o servidor para permitir tais acessos por meio de cabeçalhos HTTP [**CORS** (cross-origin resource sharing)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). No seu servidor você pode definir regras arbitrárias para qual domínios permitir ou negar o acesso de determinados domínios, inclusive podendo fazer isso de maneira dinâmica.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo pela completa resposta!
E funcionou, colocando na mesma origem!
  Embora eu ainda não esteja estudando isso, vou conseguir fazer requisição de arquivo JSON deste modo também? Você poderia me tirar esta dúvida?
Agradeço novamente!

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa usar o webserver nas duas pontas. O código está OK, mas o screenshot mostra que o `ajax.html` está sendo acessado no browser com `file:///`. Você precisa acessá-lo com HTTP também.

Comment: Adicionando informação à resposta: Não é possível fazer esse tipo de requisição utilizando o `file:///` pois os navegadores impõem uma espécie de "barreira" para fins de segurança. Veja essa resposta, é exatamente o que quero explicar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56217/23262

Comment: Ele precisa de CORS?! Só precisa alterar a URL que está usando no browser. O motivo é a barreira que você citou mesmo (política entre domínios / *cross-domain policy*).